# How to set session cookie while extracting contents from URLs using beautiful soup?

Tags: python, session, cookies, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Consider the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
content = urlopen('https://example.net/users/101')
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
divTag = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"classname"})
print(divTag)
for tag in divTag:
   ulTags = tag.find_all("ul", {"class":"classname"})
   for tag in ulTags:
       aTags = tag.find_all("li")
       for tag in aTags:
           name = tag.find('a')['href']
           print(name)
```

If i use,

```
content = open("try.html","r")
```

I get the required output.

Here, example.net can be accessed only after entering username & password. The above code does not print anything although the parsing is done correctly.How to add the session cookie value to this code ?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried requests ?

It is possible to persist cookies across a session.

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
s.post('https://example.net/users/101', data = {'username' : 'sup', 'password' : 'pass'})
r = s.get("https://example.net/users/101")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
```

more about requests.Session()

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/

Comment: how do you add multiple cookies ?